# Send data to selected socket_id

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I'm using socket.io 1.3.5 and two method

> io.to(id).emit(event,data)

and

> io.sockets.socket[id].emit(event,data)

is not working.
How to do send data to selected socket_id in socket.io 1.3.5
Sorry my english not good!

Comment: `io.to(id).emit` should work. `io.to` is used to emit to a [room](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces) but each socket is already in a room named as its own `socket.id` so it should work, unless they've changed something, I haven't used it after 1.0. Have you made sure `socket_id` is correct?

Comment: i has downgrade socket.io version to 1.2.1 and is working..