# socket.io.js returns a 404

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Upon attempting to integrate socket.io/nodejs into a page after a long absence from the projects, I'm running into a lot of problems attempting to set up the server backend for it. Installing node via nvm, (Node version `0.12.1`, socket.io version `1.3.5`)

It seems that when I attempt to run the server (via a simple `node receiver.js`), I cannot connect to `/socket.io/socket.io.js` in my `index.php` file, as seen below in provided code:

*index.php* (client side)

```
<!-- in html > head -->
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> <!-- Problem here -->
<script>
    if (typeof io === 'undefined') {
        console.error("Error connecting to nodejs backend! Expect some errors");
    }
    var socket = io();
</script>
<script src="/assets/js/selector.js"></script>
```

*receiver.js* (server side)

```
console.log('loading requirements...');

var io = require('socket.io')(80);
var net = require('net');
var mysql = require('mysql2');

console.log('connecting to mysql...');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    user: '', //removed
    password: '', //removed
    database: '', //removed
    stream: net.connect(3306, "codelanx.com")
});

var sent = {};

console.log('listening...');

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //socket.io methods, etc...
```

*selector.js* (client side)

```
//...
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    socket.emit('requestName');
    //...
}
```

On the server end, all logging statements are printed (makes it to `listening...`). I've been configuring the calling line for `require('socket.io')` and such in just about every imaginable way but still can't make this connect. Am I missing something?

Comment: where is this index.php file being served from? did you try io.on('connection'...)

Comment: @YakiKlein My `index.php` is in the webroot for the sandbox subdomain (`/var/www/sandbox` for me), and using `io.on('connection', //...)` still returned a 404 for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` (is `io.sockets` no longer used?)

Comment: Try downgrading to 1.2, [1.3.5 created some problems here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342449/send-data-to-selected-socket-id#comment46905125_29342449)

Comment: I'm not seeing any exact problem there, I'd like to know what I have to do to make it work on 1.3.5. Additionally I'd like to not use express if possible. Knowing what (and if something) changed would be helpful as well.

Comment: With just `var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);` socket.io 1.3.5 serves `/socket.io/socket.io.js` just fine for me. What if you tested a different port?

The 404 is a puzzle though. Maybe you have another localhost instance of your service running on port 80, serving the same index.php but not socket.io?

Comment: `socket.io` generates  and serves the `/socket.io/socket.io.js` resource, and I don't think you can just use it with php like this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create http server and pass it as a parameter to socket.io, and instead you are passing 80 as parameter:

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('event', function(data){});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
});
server.listen(80);
```